# Finding location of comments within a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am able to retrieve all comments for a spreadsheet. However, I want to know the exact sheet and cell range the comment is anchored to. I have looked at the values within the anchor property of the comments resource that is returned by the Comments.list() method:

```
var commentsResource = Drive.Comments.list(ss.getId());
```

In looking at the results, the only thing that I see that resembles a location is the "range" key in the json string within the "anchor" property of the resource:

```
"{"type":"workbook-range","uid":0,"range":"1303483326"}"
```

I have found documentation on *an* anchor property, but I don't believe it is applies to the one for spreadsheet comments. This is what I found: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments
There is no description on how to interpret the value for the "range" key above. And other things that documentation describes are not present in my object.

Any ideas on how to interpret the above-mentioned range value? A pointer to any doc would be brilliant. I have indeed looked exhaustively, but must not be asking the right question because I cannot find any doc on this property. Guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it can be done - the Drive API you mention lets one find comments, but not really do anything with them after that.

Comment: Related: [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23498275/1595451)

Comment: I think that you can achieve your goal by using the workaround of this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64058248/7108653

Answer (score 2):

At this time, this it's not possible. Please star the feature request about this: [Provide read/write access to comments in Google Sheets](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650)

Related Q&A

- [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15556476/1595451)
- [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23498275/1595451)