# Trying to copy comments from one google sheet to a copy of the sheet in another location using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

- Trying to copy Comments from one google sheet to a copy of the sheet in another location.
- There doesn't appear to be a copyTo() so I'm trying moveTo()
- Looking for more ideas.

Included this in the code below

It works within the same workbook:

```
// This works
function copyCellAndComments() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source_Sheet");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Destination_Sheet");
  sheet.getRange("P21:26").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("P21:26"));
};
```

```
// I run into permissions issues if I try something like
function copyCellAndComments02() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source_Sheet");
```

```
  //This didn't work.  Told me formatted wrong
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Spreadsheet URL", "Sheetname");
```

```
  // I tried using SpreadsheetApp.openById() as well as SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() in the script and it told me I don't have sufficient permissions to run openById or openByUrl.
```

```
    // (Error
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets )
```

```
  // Also tried creating a standalone function and calling the function within the sheet.
function importComments(spreadsheetKey,a1NotationReference) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetKey).getRange(a1NotationReference).getComments();
};
```

Found something online that said it would run if I added a menu and call it from the menu.

```
     // That generates an Error - Exception: Invalid argument: url (line 7, file "MyScripts_RickP")
```

I tried importrange.  Thant copies text in the comment but not as a comment.

Also tried doing it as a query wrapped around the importrange.  Same result.

This is the test comment I'm trying to copy

```
  sheet.getRange("P6").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("P6"));
};
```

Since I have not found a way to copy the sheet with it's comments intact As Comments (the comment text copies okay but I need to copy it as a comment) to the Archive location.

Answer (score 1):

### Problems

1. [getSheetbyName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) only allows you to retrieve a sheet from the same spreadsheet and requires you to specify the sheet name only, without the spreadsheet URL
2. The method `getComments()` for spreadsheets is depricated. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818) for this functionality, but currently it is not implemented

### Workaround

- If you want to [copy a sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) into a different spreadsheet, you can do it as following:

```
  var targetSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID');
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Source_Sheet").copyTo(targetSheet);
```

However, this will not copy the comments.

- Same applies to other copy methods like `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy('This is a copy');` or `DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).makeCopy();`
- You can retrieve the comments with the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive):

`var comments=Drive.Comments.list(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());`

- You can use the retrieved comment to create a comment in the destination file, e.g.:

`Drive.Comments.insert({"content":comments.items[0].content, "context":comments.items[0].context, "author":comments.items[0].author}, targetSheet.getId());`

- [Comments.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/insert) allows you to specify different [parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource), also the [anchor](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#anchor), however the latter is [trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249441/finding-location-of-comments-within-a-google-sheet) to pass from the original comment to the destination.